# Slow Wifi on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using Thinkpad x201 with Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000

Tags: intel-wireless, iwlwifi

This problems keeps coming up on StackExchange but seem to not be properly solved. If anyone can give proper guidance as to how to fix it that would be super appreciated.

Problem Description: 
While being connected to Wifi the connection is terribly slow. Running speed-test with Win7 on the very same machine and on another Mac machine result in much higher speeds (~10-100 fold or more).

Using the terminal to check my hardware type: `lspci | grep -i network` I get the following

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Gigabit is the Ethernet, not the wifi.  No wifi runs Gig.

Comment: Thank for that Thomas, I'm new to Linux and still don't know which is what.. Trying to solve it. Thanks

Comment: "Ethernet controller" always is your wired connection.  That's what "Ethernet" is.  Just something to learn for the future.  :P

Comment: Right, I could have known myself.. I didn't realize its kind of stupid. Any suggestions for solutions perhaps?

Comment: In many posts I see suggestions to dowload the latest drivers from backport  [http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi/], Since I'm new to that, there things I am not sure about:     **1.** How do I know which driver fits my wireless card as there are two options there (Intel® Centrino® Wireless-N 1000
2.6.30+
iwlwifi-1000-ucode-128.50.3.1.tgz
3.2+
iwlwifi-1000-ucode-39.31.5.1.tgz  ).   **2.** what do I do with those files once extracted to a folder?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a X201, but with a  Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35) Wifi controler.
One thing that helped was to go to the bios setup, load the default configuration and save changes. But this was only temporarily.
For another reason I disabled DHCP and set a fix IP to the wifi connection. Since than the Problem is gone.
The download speed increased from not 1 Mbit to 10 Mbit.